# Insert a datetime value with SSIS to an datetime column in a table on a IBM AS/400 library/system

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, db2, ibm-midrange

I have the following problem.

I want make a SSIS flow that inserts values from a table in a MS SQL server database to a table in a AS/400 library.

This works for all the values but the datetime2 value. I tried to insert a datetime2 value and a varchar value in the datetime2 format. Both ways did not work.

It gives the following error:

> [TABLENAME [11566]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "IBMDA400 Command"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "CWBZZ5014 Value of parameter COLUMNNAME could not be converted to the host data type.".
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "IBMDA400 Command"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "CWBZZ5014 Value of parameter COLUMNNAME could not be converted to the host data type.".
>
> [TABLENAME [11566]] Error: There was an error with input column "COLUMNAME" (12245) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (11579). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Does someone knows how to get this done?

Comment: What's the target column data type?

Comment: Its a timestamp with a lenght of 26. The format is: 2016-12-16-11.30.58.161468

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume conversion in sql scripting could be better way of mapping destination column in IBM , try this.

`CONVERT(TIMESTAMP, @DateTimeVariable )` or

use `derived column` expression and there by use `data conversion`.

I would like to try db_timestamp

Data Conversion

[image]

Comment: I used DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 with a scale of 6 and it works! Thanks